# Double value negative after multiplication -Java

Tags: java

In my code i have following line.

```
double temp=(c12*fileSize);
```

- Here c12 is double and fileSizeis double
- c12 have a value 1700 and
- fileSize have a value 1944038

but after multiplication i am getting `-990102696`.

Can any one help me on it? Is that some size limits went wrong?

Comment: The size of a file (in bytes) is always an integral type, with no partial bytes... `long` is typically used for it. And `c12`, whatever it is, could be an `int` or `long` in this example as well... `temp` would need to be `long` too.

Comment: By the way, why are you trying to store a file size in a double? Are you expecting that you could have fractions of a byte in your file? Hmm, if file A is only 3 bits and file B is only 5 bits, then I should be able to store both files in one byte on my hard drive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your c12 and fileSize are most likely ints (+1 Tomasz).  Java multiplies the ints, which overflows, becoming negative, and then stores that negative value in your double.  Cast c12 and fileSize to double before multiplying:

```
double c12 = 1700, fileSize = 1944038;
System.out.println(c12 * fileSize);
```

produces:

```
3.3048646E9
```

Comment: thanks alpian thats works I was handling one of the varibales as integer which was the problem

Comment: Hi alpian,  double d = 0.0;
  double e = -1 * 0.0;
  
  System.out.println(d * -2  );
  System.out.println(e);  This gives me -0.0 as result. can you explain. you can consider double e = -1.0 * 0.0; also which gives -0.0

Answer (score 9):

`(int)1700 * (int)1944038` is equal to your `-990102696`.

Are you sure `c12` and `fileSize` aren't integers? If they are, the multiplication occurs with integer types, integer overflow and it is being promoted to `double` *afterwards*.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I just tried that and I get "3.3048646E9". You shouldn't get any overflow wrap around on a double: if you exceed the maximum, it should turn into "Infinity".

I suspect the problem is in whatever you're trying to do to write this number. Or maybe you need to show us some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a double on the fly:

```
double temp=(c12*1.0*fileSize);
```

else, an c12 as int will be multiplied by another int, and the result overflows, and is later - too late - converted to double.

```
c12 = 1700.0 
// or 
filesize = 1944038f
```

would help, but a filesize as float/double looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

```
    double c12 = 1700;
    double fileSize = 1944038;
    double temp=(c12*fileSize);
    System.out.println(temp);
```

Gives 3.3048646E9

I bet your c12 and fileSize are ints.